# Changing the link in a Content Query Web Part

Tags: content-query-web-part

I have added the Content Query Web Part to my page.

I've hooked it up to a custom list that I've added a Url column to.

The list is displaying on my page, but the link goes to the list item properties page, not to the url column within the list.

I assumed it would be straight forward to change the functionality to link to my url column instead, but I've not been able to do so.

I'm updating the following section, and I get this error message

> "Url is not a valid hyperlink field or
>   URL Path. Leave the field blank to
>   automatically generate a link to the
>   view properties form of the returned
>   items."

[image]

I have confirmed that Url is the internal name of a column in the list I'm linking to.
Also the contents of the Url column are all `http://www.google.com/1`

How can I link to my url column in the Content Query Web Part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure the URL column is created as a hyperlink type, not as a string, and then populated with a URL.

Comment: @Tim... so simple, yet so many hours!!

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ecm/whats-new-with-the-content-query-web-part) article. It shows you how to replace the fields you want to render, using the "fields to display" section.

Another article from MSDN [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms497457%28v=office.14%29) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/aa981241%28v=office.14%29).

Comment: @Anders.... are you missing a word up there "render, using the ???"

Comment: thanks I've updated my question to be a bit more specific... that was the area I've been playing around with, but wasnt sure... and wasnt getting it to work.

Comment: The field is using display names. I guess this is to make it easier for end users (designers) to add fields. Try with the display name for URL

Answer (score 0):

The solution we found for this is to use the field name `FileRef`. If you apply the change, the Link field will reset to `Name (linked to document)`, but the fileref change should stick, regardless.

Apparently, `FileRef` is the internal field name for the URL field.
How Microsoft expected anyone to work this out for themselves is anyone's guess!